# Showing multiple data with same x and y in highchart

Tags: javascript, react-native, highcharts

I try using highchart in react-native to show 6 data from the state, and it works the data shown. But because the 6 data have same X and Y, so the data were shown but stacking so it looks like there is only one data (the X is the time when the data get the post, and the Y the day when the data get the post). Is there any way to make the data all appear in the chart.

This is the chart look like :

[image]

This is my highchart conf :

```
var conf= {
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            backgroundColor: '#233767',
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          labels: {
              formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.value);
              },
              style:{
                color:'white'
              }
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
           type: 'datetime',
           lineWidth: 1,
           dateTimeLabelFormats: {
             minute: '%H:%M'
           },
           labels: {
                style:{
                    color:'white'
                  }
           },
           title: {
             enabled: false
           },
           gridLineColor:'transparent'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
              Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x) + '<br/>' +
              Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.y);
          },
        },
        credits: false,
        exporting:  false,
        legend: {
          itemStyle: {
            color: '#FFFF',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        title: false,
        series: this.state.chartState
      }
```

Comment: Can you not represent your data in a different way?  I think this is more of a https://ux.stackexchange.com/ discussion than a code discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example distinguish points by using different `radius`:

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [10, 10]
  ],
  marker: {
    radius: 10
  }
}, {
  data: [
    [10, 10]
  ],
  marker: {
    radius: 5
  }
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tm0v6fw4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.marker.radius

---

Or use multiple axis with different scale:

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [10, 10]
  ]
}, {
  data: [
    [10, 10]
  ],
  yAxis: 1
}, {
  data: [
    [10, 10]
  ],
  yAxis: 2
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qwj4mu7n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: I might be the only one but your jsfiddle links do not seem to load.

Comment: Hi @Clafou, Hm, that's strange - working for me. Please check on a different browser.

Comment: Same thing on latest Chrome and Safari. Also tried on a another computer without success. Not sure what's wrong to be honest. Anyway, your examples should be sufficient :)

Comment: Could you check this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zb5wnvgf/1/ link?